Derivation of the Reissner-Nordstrom metric
I was reading Carroll's book, spacetime and geometry and I wanted to try to derive the Reissner-Nordstrom metric as it was said that it was dissimilar to the Schwarzschild solution. But I can't seem to figure it out. Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I think this is one of the problems on Wald's chapter 6. Hint: show that the Coulomb field is the unique spherically symmetric solution to Maxwell's equations in the absence of charges, compute its stress tensor, and then solve the Einstein equation in the way you did when solving for Schwarzschild

Here is a thesis that derives it.
